# Can't log into arch and pacman won't open following a botched update, need to recover data

Tags: linux, data-recovery, arch-linux

## Highlighted Info - For quick reply

- Attempting to enter a username to Arch Linux results in `Login failed.` and no reply to input a user's password.
- Arch-chrooting into the partitions ends up with pacman responding with `error while loading shared libraries: libgsap_krb5.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
- Attempting to view `/home/nature` results in one file being returned within the directory "install_pacaur.sh" which is the file I used when setting up Arch.
- Data recovery seems to be impossible (according to my knowledge) unless I am able to login to the OS and mount a vfat formated USB. (I need to recover two .odt documents)
- I only need to recover files from my home partition; the OS is unimportant.

## What happened

Earlier today I was updating my laptop's Arch packages and for some reason a few packages were deleted, missing, or corrupt. The following packages were maintained by [Levente Polyak](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?packager=anthraxx) on the Arch repository: krb5, jasper, libpsl, and etcetera. I can not determine how many packages were effected on my system, but I assume a minuscule amount of somewhere around 5.

## Issue

Due to this mishap, my computer seems not to function and every time a username is entered the computer returns `Login failed.`. I assume this issue has to do with krb5. Furthermore upon arch-chrooting into the partitions and mounting, pacman does not work and results with the follow output: `pacman: error while loading shared libraries: libgsap_krb5.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Any help would be graciously appreciated as I have some valuable notes stored on my laptop that need to be recovered. (These were taken in the last week, so I had not backed up to the cloud yet.) The notes are needed for an exam I am having tomorrow, so any reply is graciously appreciated. I will take this instance to only use Arch for my home desktop and switch my laptop to a more stable OS.

edit: Please let me know if any further information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you seem to already have a rescue medium available, use it to reinstall the broken packages: assuming the rootfs is mounted on `/mnt`,

```
pacman -r /mnt -Syu krb5
 - or -
pacstrap /mnt krb5
```

will reinstall the broken package *without* needing a chroot. Afterwards do a package check to find out what other packages, if any, are missing their files:

```
pacman -r /mnt -Qqkk
```

and reinstall those using `pacman -r …` as well.

---

Second, from the looks of it, you have a separate `/home` partition – so you'll have to actually `mount` it first before trying to access your files.

Check `/mnt/etc/fstab` or run `lsblk` or `lsblk -f` to see which partition it is.

Comment: The -r attribute was very helpful. I actually installed it manually before your reply and happened to get the login and pacman to work, but still had no luck extracting with a medium. I used the pacman -r command to update my file system and was able to successfully mount the vfat usb and extract my data. Thanks for the help!